# Can't bind DatagramSocket on "0.0.0.0"

Tags: c#, udp, windows-runtime, datagram

in Win RT we have to use DatagramSocket instead of UdpClient. Ok but the following code gives me this error which I don't get on UdpClient.

```
        var g = new DatagramSocket();
        g.MessageReceived += g_MessageReceived;
        await g.BindEndpointAsync(new HostName("0.0.0.0"), "5000"); //<--- this line
```

*IPAddress.Any = 0.0.0.0

I get this Error:
"No such host is known. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072AF9)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To bind to all local interfaces (the way binding 0.0.0.0 aka INADDR_ANY does with the Berkeley Sockets API), use [`BindServiceNameAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701211).

> The `BindServiceNameAsync` method binds to the local IP addresses of all network interfaces on the local computer on the local service name or UDP port specified in the `localServiceName` parameter. If the `localServiceName` parameter is an empty string, the system will select the local UDP port on which to bind.

Comment: You may can help me handle this too! http://stackoverflow.com/users/103167/ben-voigt

Comment: OMG !!! what a silly move :) here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656372/datagramsocket-cannot-receive-data-from-udpclient